# Pointer initialization: address or value

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question regarding pointer initialization in C.

I understand that `*ptr` will give the value of that pointer is pointing to.

`ptr` will give you the address.

Now I got following syntax:

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Why is `*ptr` being initialized with an address of the Heap and not a value? `malloc()` returns an address right?

Shouldn't it be:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(...);
```

Comment: Mentally separate `int *` (pointer to `int`) from `ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*ptr));` and you have your answer.

Comment: The "problem" is that `*` is context-sensitive. It means "pointer to" in one context, "pointer dereference" in another and "multiplication" as well.

Comment: OT: Noho need to cast `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: In C you [don't have to cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (and such a cast could actually lead to bugs).

Comment: That is a **declaration**, when declaring a variable read it in reverse order and you'll get the sense: `int *ptr`=> **ptr** is a variable that deferenced with `*` gives an `int`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: The `*` in a declaration and in an expression is not actually different or context-sensitive. In both cases, it means a dereference. The key is to realize that a declaration provides a picture of how something will be used. `int *ptr` says “When I use `*ptr`, that is an `int`.” So the `*` is a dereference operator; it is saying “When I dereference `ptr`, that is an `int`”. The declarator is a model of an expression, so the operators in it model the same meanings as in expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `*ptr`, `*` is acting as the *dereferencing operator*.

With `int *ptr`, `*` is acting as part of the type declaration for `ptr`.

So the two things are entirely different, even though `*` is used. (Multiplication and comment blocks are further uses of `*` in C).

Answer (score 5):

In that line, `int *` is the type.

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Is just this compressed into one line:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Comment: I think this is why I prefer to initialize it as `int* ptr` rather than `int *ptr`. This isn't a universal view, though.

Comment: Thank you. So this would be wrong? 
 int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco Indeed it isn't - particularly in instances like `int* ptr, variable;`

Comment: @davidev What makes you think `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` is wrong?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I thought I need to assign a value after =, because I used *. But now I understood that the * is part of the declaration.

Comment: @davidev but you are assigning the return value of `malloc` to the variable `ptr`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes I know. That's why I ask that question. Malloc returns a address in heap and I thought I need a int literal.

Answer (score 2):

Actually , this:

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Is just short syntax for this:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(...);
```

The * is used for defining a type pointer and not to dereference the pointer .

Answer (score 2):

Both snippets above do the same thing.

In the first case, the `*` before `ptr` is not the derefernece operator but is part of the definition of the type.  So you actually are assigning a value to (initializing, actually) `ptr`, not `*ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

and

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(...);
```

is basically the same as the difference between

```
int i = 5;
```

and

```
int i;
i = 5;
```

The first variant defines and initializes a variable in one go. The second variant defines the variable but leave it uninitialized, and then assign a value to it.

Comment: Okay thank you. So when I declare a pointer it expects an address after = ? No value right? I was confused because I used * at the beginning, but this is just for the definition of the pointer right?

Comment: @davidev A pointer *is* a value, it's just interpreted differently by the compiler.